# How can I write the same code using switch statement and the full word instead of initials?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Please consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    enum object {rock, paper, scissors};
    object player1, player2;
    cout << " "Enter "r" for rock, "p" for paper or "s" for scissors:";
    char p1, p2;
    cin >> p1 >> p2;

    if (p1 == 'r') {player1 = rock;}
    else if (p1 == 'p') {player1 = paper;}
    else if (p1 == 's') {player1 = scissors;}
    else {cout << "invalid input, play again" << endl; exit(1);}

    if (p2 == 'r') {player2 = rock;}
    else if (p2 == 'p') {player2 = paper;}
    else if (p2 == 's') {player2 = scissors;}
    else {cout << "invalid input, play again" << endl; exit(1);}

    if (player1==player2) cout <<"objects are equal";
    else if (player1==rock && player2==paper) cout << "player 2 is the winner";
    else if (player1==rock && player2==scissors) cout<<"player 1 is the winner";
    else if (player1==paper && player2==rock) cout << "player 1 is the winner";
    else if (player1==paper && player2==scissors) cout <<"Palyer 2 is the winnder";
    else if (player1==scissors && player2==paper) cout << "Player 1 is winner";
    else cout <<"Player 2 is the winner";
    cout << endl;
}
```

How can the above code be rewritten with the switch statement while the user has to give the full word (rock, paper, scissors) instead of the initials for the input.

**Update:** I have converted part of the code with switch, but I was interested to see if I could use it for the entire code:

For instance:

```
switch (p1) {
        case 'r': player1=rock; break;
        case 'p': player1=paper; break;
        case 's': player1=scissors; break;
    }
```

instead of

```
if (p1 == 'r') {player1 = rock;}
    else if (p1 == 'p') {player1 = paper;}
    else if (p1 == 's') {player1 = scissors;}
    else {cout << "invalid input, play again" << endl; exit(1);}
```

Comment: Granted there are only 3 items, but you could use a `std::map` to get rid of the `switch` and a lot of those `if / else` statements.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why reopen?  The OP wants to switch on strings, the dupe says they can't

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica See my answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow If you wan to add something, you add it to the dupe, you don't reopen the question.  Now the information is segregated instead of integrated,

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it this simple. `switch` does not work with strings. You could however circumvent this problem and calculate the `object` before doing the switch:

```
std::string player1Input, player2Input;
//...
std::cin >> player1Input >> player2Input;

object player1Choice = getChoice(player1Input);
object player2Choice = getChoice(player2Input);
```

Where `getChoice` could look like this:

```
object getChoice(std::string input)
{
    if(input == "rock")
        return object::rock;
    else if(input == "paper")
        return object::paper;
    else if(input == "scisor")
        return object::sciscor;
    else {
        //invalid input
    }
}
```

Then you can use your switch:

```
switch(player1Choice)
{
case object::rock:
    switch(player2Choice)
    {
    case object::rock: //rock vs rock
        break;
    ...
    };

    break;
...
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution to my question. But I get the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'player1'" for cin << player1 << player2; How can I get rid of that?

Comment: @developer oops, sorry, that's a typo, I fixed it :)

Comment: Now I getting this error: Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>') and 'std::__1::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >'))

Comment: Yes, I think I need a break.

Comment: @developer I meant myself, because of the two typos ;) but breaks are always good ^^

Comment: Yes, I agree with that :)

Comment: I get (Function definition is not allowed here) for (object getChoice (string input){)

Comment: That's three different pieces of code. I trust you to put them where they are needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

It can't.

`switch` works on built-in types, like `int`, `bool` and `char`.

It is not a complex comparison feature that can perform checks on strings.

Comment: Thank you! So that is why the original code uses initials instead of the full words.

Comment: @developer Yep, probably.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

const char * object_name[] = { "rock", "paper", "scissors" };
enum object {rock, paper, scissors};

std::string choice;
std::cin >> choice;

//...

auto it = std::find_if( std::begin( object_name ), std::end( object_name ),
                        [&choice]( const char *item )
                        {
                            return choice == item;
                        } );

if ( it != std::end( object_name ) )
{
    int p1 = std::distance( std::begin( object_name ), it );

    switch ( p1 )
    {
    case rock:
        //...
        break;
    case paper:
        //...
        break;
    case scissors:
        //...
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    const char * object_name[] = { "rock", "paper", "scissors" };
    enum object {rock, paper, scissors};

    std::string choice;

    std::cout << "Enter \"" << object_name[0] << "\", or \""  << object_name[1]
              << "\", or \"" << object_name[2] << "\": ";
    std::cin >> choice;

    auto it = std::find_if( std::begin( object_name ), std::end( object_name ),
                        [&choice]( const char *item )
                        {
                            return choice == item;
                        } );

    if ( it != std::end( object_name ) )
    {
        int p1 = std::distance( std::begin( object_name ), it );

        switch ( p1 )
        {
        case rock:
            std::cout << object_name[rock];
            break;

        case paper:
            std::cout << object_name[paper];
            break;
        case scissors:
            std::cout << object_name[scissors];
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter "rock", or "paper", or "scissors": paper
paper
```

Comment: Thanks but I think this one is beyond the limits of my current knowledge of cpp coding. I am trying to explain the lines to myself.

Comment: @developer See the demonstrative program added to my answer.